# Jruby rb to java generated class inheritance support or workarounds

Tags: jruby

I am experimenting around with JRuby - generating java from ruby files. I have an abstract class in ruby that implement a Java interface, and child classes extending this. also in ruby.

I'm running into the problem as described on http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6342 where all the generated java files only extend RubyObject.

I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this and have a workaround? Right now I have used a java_implement interface in each child class as they do not extend the abstract class.

I have included the snippet from JRUBY-6342 describing the problem:

> The Java code generated by jrubyc --java does not appear to support Ruby class inheritance. Given the following simple example:
>
> class A
>        def my_class; self.class.name end
>      end
>
> class B < A
>      end
>
> The generated class in B.java inherits from RubyObject rather than A, rendering the B class completely broken in Java.
>   On a somewhat related note, module inclusion doesn't seem to work either. A class with include M doesn't get M's methods in the generated Java code.

Am I missing something in my understanding of Ruby or JRuby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still an issue indeed as the jruby compiler [still produces RubyObject](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/lib/ruby/shared/jruby/compiler/java_class.rb#L464) for the classes.

The only workaround that I know to this is to use the JRuby `ScriptEngine` from Java to eval your JRuby code.  For example, here is some JRuby code:

```
require 'java'

java_import 'javax.swing.JFrame'
java_import 'javax.swing.JButton'

class MyFrame < JFrame
  def initialize
    super('Test')
    content_pane.add(JButton.new("Hello"))
    pack()
  end
end
```

This code can then be called from a Java class like this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("jruby");
        Reader reader = new FileReader("myframe.rb");
        engine.eval(reader);

        // Instantiate the JRuby class, and cast the result of eval.
        JFrame frame = (JFrame) engine.eval("MyFrame.new");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here the object returned by `eval` can be casted into `JFrame`, just as you would expect.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721134/is-it-possible-to-create-java-classes-from-jruby-and-use-them-in-java) for that problem.